# What exactly happened in Roswell, NM in-universe and how was it related to Asgard?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

[Stargate Wikia](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Roswell) says that

> Roswell is a city in New Mexico on Earth. It is the location of a rumored crash landing of an alien spacecraft in 1947. (SG1: "Thor's Chariot", "Out of Mind", "Prometheus")

There seems to be two references that **hint** at the fact that the crash had something to do with Asgard:

1. In the episode "Out of Mind", O'Neill implied that the Asgard have a connection to Roswell:

   > **Hathor:** How do we contact the Asgard so that we might align with their forces?
   >   **O'Neill:** Try Roswell. Little place in New Mexico.
2. In "Thor's Chariot", the Asgard's true form looks like a stereotypical "[Roswell grey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_alien)" alien, and Carter-alternate even refers to them by that name in "Point of View" episode.

Was there any information (from episodes, or official info from creators) that clarified what exactly happened in Roswell in 1947; and whether the Asgard were involved?

Comment: I have to rewatch the episode, but #1 sounds like it's just one of O'Neill's jokes.  It likely isn't much of an in universe serious reference to be used as a basis for anything.  #2 is solid though.

Comment: I have the odd feeling that if there was further mention of it, it would have been in the [Loki episode](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Fragile_Balance), but nothing to back that up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no in-universe mention of the Roswell crash aside from O'Neill's jokes to Hathor. Thor mentions, in fact, that no Asgard vessel had ever been detected while orbiting Earth, though he does not mention crashes. One would imagine the lack of any foreknowledge of the Asgard by the US military or government would indicate that the Roswell crash was either not alien-related in the *Stargate* universe, or at least that it wasn't Asgard-related.

The prevalence of "Grey" aliens in abduction accounts is explained by Loki's actions in abducting humans for his experiments for decades, possibly centuries. Area 51 is common to both Roswell mythology and the *SG-1* universe, but that's it.

Comment: Area 51 in the _Stargate_ franchise is basically the same facility as it is in the real world: development and testing of aircraft and weapons. Except in _Stargate_, the people working there get to dissect actual alien technology.

Comment: So, like you said, just like the real world ;).

Comment: There IS an In-Universe-Mention IF you consider the books, in particular: http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1:_Roswell. And Loki has something to do with it :)